# Why was this post deleted as spam or offensive?

Tags: support, review-audits, deleted-answers, spam

Today while I was reviewing Low quality posts, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20140140) was given to me as an audit which I failed because I reviewed it as LOOKS OK. The post actually LOOKS OK. It was deleted as spam which I think because of the link. But that link too has some relevant material to the question. Was that a mistake?

---

There's a comment for [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20140140) which blames that the user have linked his own site. But I have found no relevant information to prove that statement.

Comment: there is a similar deleted answer on that same question so it looks like this was a persistent spammer.

Comment: After passing the audit, you should be able to see the comment under it. *When linking to your own site, please indicate that in the post. Saying you "found" a "link" is misleading, to put it nicely.* It suggests it's some overt self-promotion.

Comment: You can [read through the help center article on spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to see what types of activities are considered spam, which this post engages in.

Comment: @iBug how can you prove that link is one of his sites? The site referring that link does not have his name or anything to identify him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That user had a history of posting links to their ad-plastered website. First they did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48964092/19679), was warned about it, then continued to post [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50669107/19679) (which members of the community called out as spam), and proceeded to [re-post that link on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50767600/19679) once their first answer was deleted. The "I found some more effective link for this solution" is a lie, and is undisclosed self-promotion.

They appeared to be here just to promote their own site, at which point a moderator marked their posts as spam. Not sure why the account wasn't destroyed at the same time, so I've taken care of that now.

Comment: Should this really be used as an audit then, given that the evidence they are a spammer is in their deleted post history?

Comment: @Radiodef This is exactly the type of spam that we want users finding and dealing with in review, so yes.  You should be suspicious of posts that are promoting 3rd party products, particularly in review, to look for warning signs or clear indications that the post is in fact spam.  That's one of the higher priorities for you as a reviewer.  Some spam is very obvious, but lots of spammers try to hide their tracks and make it appear, at first glance, to not be spam.  Part of reviewing is being able to see through such behaviors.

Comment: @Servy So the correct action in this sort of case is to click out of the review queue to investigate, at which point we would discover it's an audit because the post and user are deleted? (And the fact that we would pass the audit by discovering it's an audit doesn't matter. We took the correct action by leaving the queue to investigate.)

Comment: @Radiodef: Yes. Spam audits are just there as a honeypot for robo-reviewers who don't actually review but are okaying everything they see just to meet a daily quota.